# C# app hangs not able to enter a method

Tags: c#, constructor, static, parallel-processing

I have encountered one of the wierdest errors in my life. My app simply hangs once I try to call a harmless method. The worst thing about it is that the Visual Studio's debuger can't show anything useful, all I see is that the app is trying to call a method but cannot even enter it! When I press the "pause" button it just shows this:

[image]

And the app keeps being unresponsive ever since! Nothing works F10, F11, F5 - it cannot enter a method.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually the method call itself? VS sometimes shows the next command instead of the one that "really" hangs. Perhaps one of the conditions is blocking or breaking stuff? Are you using something derived from `MarshalByRefObject` or specifying the `Synchronized` attribute?

Comment: I had a thread running in the background, when I shut it down and run the code again, the pause button stopped the code in a different place - check the answer.

Comment: Well, remember in the future that you can change the thread you're looking at - either in the Threads window, or Parallel Stacks. It's very useful when debugging multi-threaded applications :)

Comment: wow, thanks man :) Thanks indeed - never knew that :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I was using `Parallel.For` in the static constructor of GaussianAITable class like this:

```
    Parallel.For(0, ColumnCount, i =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < RowCount; ++j)
            {
                WorldPosition[i, j].X = (i - HalfColumnCount) * ColumnSize + ColumnSize / 2;
                WorldPosition[i, j].Y = (j - HalfRowCount) * RowSize + RowSize / 2;
            }
        });
```

I identified the problem, when I removed all of my parallel code and then tried to launch the same method again. The app hanged, but when I pressed the "pause" button it ended up in the static constructor - still trying to finish the job. I must note that the job itself is harmless and with simple `for` loop instead of `Parallel.For` it finishes quite fast. C# is terrible with its static constructors, they are almost undebuggable, I was lucky to find this one. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Well, nobody forces you to use static constructors :) They really aren't designed for running *parallelized CPU intensive tasks*.

Comment: They are sometimes usefull :) Not mah code though :) cleaning up after a co-worker :). I don't like static constructors either.

Comment: For a case like this, at the very least, I'd let the code run in something like `Lazy`. But yeah, ideally you'd like to initialize those things predictably rather than relying on static constructors. Maybe even not using static fields in the first place (although I can understand trying to avoid indirection in game code, it's still something that should nowadays be based on profiler results and not just 30 year old practices :))).